# Elasticsearch Placeholder Months in Date Range Query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an aggregation query that is working well:

```
  aggs: {
    by_month: {
      date_histogram: {
        field: "created_at",
        interval: interval
      },
```

This prints out what I need, created by month. There is a whole month where I don't have data (December 2015) and it doesn't come back at all in the data. Is there anyway to make it print "placeholder" months? Or does this need to be handled by the application logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
aggs: {
    by_month: {
      date_histogram: {
        field: "created_at",
        interval: interval,
        min_doc_count: 0
      },
```

min_doc_count set to 0 "fills out" the extra months!